# Why use anchor.href property to process url

Tags: javascript

I've found the following code today:

```
var baseHref = document.createElement('a');
baseHref.href = this.baseURL;
baseHref = baseHref.pathname;
```

where `this.baseURL` is string.

It seems that it takes advantage of some conversion functionality that is perform when `href` is set or `pathname` is read. It's just an assumption. What is this functionality? Or what other uses can be?

Comment: Is this wrapped inside of a function?

Comment: what's `baseURL`? It seems to be a convoluted way to get your current page

Comment: I believe it's just a way to resolve a relative URL. If you set the `href` of an `a` tag and then get that `a` tag's `pathname`, it will prepend the URL's path. [An example](https://jsfiddle.net/k5xLx6jd/1/)

Comment: @Santi, thanks for your example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating an anchor, and passing in an URL, takes advantage of the browsers built in parser for URL's, so different parts of the URL can be returned easily, with no regular expressions or string manipulation.

The `pathname` is ... well, the pathname after the protocol and hostname etc.

A small example, with some of the parts that can be returned this way

```js
var baseHref = document.createElement('a');
baseHref.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com:3333/page/that/goes/somewhere?querystring=test#hash';

console.log('protocol    : ', baseHref.protocol);
console.log('host        : ', baseHref.host);
console.log('hostname    : ', baseHref.hostname);
console.log('port        : ', baseHref.port);
console.log('pathname    : ', baseHref.pathname);
console.log('querystring : ', baseHref.search);
console.log('hash        : ', baseHref.hash);
```

This is really just a neat trick to parse URL's using the browser.

Comment: thanks, do you think [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179432/why-use-anchor-href-property-to-process-url?noredirect=1#comment79321706_46179432) is also possible?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, the comment by @Santi just shows an example of getting the pathname?

Comment: the part about resolving relative URL

Comment: In a way it is. The `href` property will generally return an absolute URL, even when the property is set to a relative URL, so it could be used as a way to get the current absolute pathname from passing in just a relative URL